# Loading a Database in CodeIgniter

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, pdo

I want to connect to a postgresql database in CodeIgniter via the pdo-driver.
Doing it manually works without any Problems:

```
$gp = new PDO("pgsql:host=pdca.example.de;port=5432;sslmode=require;dbname=dssprod;",$techUser,$techPW);
$query = $gp->query('select * from table limit 10');
$result = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
var_dump($result);
```

doing the same within CodeIgniter in config\database.php :

```
$active_group = 'default';
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => "pgsql:host=pdca.example.de;port=5432;sslmode=require;dbname=dssprod;",
    'username' => $techUser,
    'password' => $techPW,
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo'
);
```

and then in a view:

```
$connect = $this -> load -> database();
var_dump($connect);
```

--> results in a bool(false)

I can't get a Connection to the db with CodeIgniter, any idea why?

--- edit ---

I tried a config without pdo, same result (false).

```
$active_group = 'default';
$db['default'] = array(
    'hostname' => 'pdca.example.de',
    'port' => 5432,
    'sslmode' => 'require',
    'username' => $techUser,
    'password' => $techPW,
    'database' => 'dssprod',
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'save_queries' => FALSE
);
```

Comment: Enable Postgresql extension in php.ini
extension=php_pgsql.dll

Comment: the Extension was / is enabled